# php preg match parse html

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I am trying to get **1,9110** from the string:

```
<span class="c_name">€ EUR</span> <span class="c_value">1,9110</span>
```

And my code is:

```
// EUR //
if(preg_match('/<span class="c_name">€ EUR<\/span> <span class="c_value">(.*?)<\/span>/mis', $rawresult, $result))
{
    $banks['access']['sale']['EUR'] = $result[1];
} else {
    $banks['access']['sale']['EUR'] = false;
}
var_dump($banks);
// EUR //
```

But this code isn't working

Comment: Umm, yes it is? `$result[1] = "1,9110"`.

Comment: no not worked. Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: invalid UTF-8 string at offset 21

Comment: egg I updated my code

Comment: run a `htmlspecialchars()` on the string and use `&euro;` in the match

Comment: not worked  for me

Comment: Works for me on PHP7. Maybe my PCRE UTF-8 flag is enabled. Looks like you have a great alternative to preg_match below.

Comment: It could be worth to have a look at the coding of your source file. Also make sure there are no disturbing additional invisible bytes. -- You could also try to use `mb_ereg()`, the multi byte version of `preg_match()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regex crashes on the euro-sign.
Try to escape it like this:

```
if(preg_match('/<span class="c_name">\x{20AC} EUR<\/span> <span class="c_value">(.*?)<\/span>/misu', $rawresult, $result))
```

Comment: Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: character value in \x{} or \o{} is too large at offset 28 in

Comment: Yup, forgot to add u as param, added it just now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a regular expression for this, you can just use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) with a specific flag to allow the thousands

```
echo filter_var('<span class="c_name">€ EUR</span> <span class="c_value">1,9110</span>', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND);
```

https://eval.in/534892

Answer (score 0):

```
'<span class="c_value">(.*?)<\/span>/s';
```

or try

```
if(preg_match('/<span class="c_name">.*?EUR<\/span> <span class="c_value">(.*?)<\/span>/mis', $rawresult, $result))
```